# C++ linked list notation, what is the difference?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, notation

I just want to know if there is and difference between these two notations:

First example:

```
    struct node{
      int data;
      node* next;
   };
```

```
    void insert(node* list){
      node* n,* last;
      last = list;
      while(last)
         last = last -> next;
      n = new node;
      last = n;
      n -> next = NULL;
      cin >> n -> data;
   }
```

```
    int main(){
      node* list = new node;
      list -> next = NULL;
      insert(list);
      return 0;
    }
```

Second example:

```
    struct node{
      int data;
      node* next;
   };
```

```
    void insert(node* list){
      node* n,* last;
      last = list -> next;
      while(last)
         last = last -> next;
      n = new node;
      last = n;
      n -> next = NULL;
      cin >> n -> data;
   }
```

```
    int main(){
      node* list = new node;
      list -> next = NULL;
      insert(list);
      return 0;
    }
```

So I wonder if there is difference between notation lie:
in first example:

```
last = list;
```

and in second example

```
last = lista -> next;
```

And what does node* list do/represent in void insert(node* list){}
Is that just a pointer to whatever list, a pointer that points to the list in the main, or what?

Comment: Obviously, there is a difference. What if `list` is a null pointer?

Comment: One thing they certainly have in common - neither example compiles, because `lista` is an undeclared identifier.

Comment: You're leaking a lot of memory in your code. And try to use RAII.

Comment: yes, I know I didn't deallocate memory, I just wanted to know the difference but now I think I got it. Thanks for the info @JHBonarius, yours and Evg7's  comments are the only useful comments here, others just downvote it, or point out the typos, so thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your above explanation stands correct but let me also add one more point, Suppose your

```
list = NULL;

void insert(node* list){
  node* n,* last;
  last = list -> next;
  while(last)
     last = last -> next;
  n = new node;
  last = n;
  n -> next = NULL;
  cin >> n -> data;
```

}

Then in the above case you are trying to access `list->next` which is next of 'NULL' thus it will give you runtime error because you cant access next of nullptr as it is not defined.

Comment: Thank you for the update of the answer ;)

Comment: Pleasure is all mine @Demigod98 ! Happy to share (-:

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node{
  int data;
  node* next;
};

void insert(node* list){
  node* n,* last;
  last = list;
  while(last -> next)
     last = last -> next;
  n = new node;
  last = n;
  n -> next = NULL;
  cin >> n -> data;
}

int main(){
  node* list = new node;
  list -> next = NULL;
  insert(list);
  return 0;
}
```

Well, obviously nobody wanted to give me an answer so I've found it myself. This is how to code should look like.
The reason why:

```
last = list -> next;
```

won't work is the following : list -> next is declared as NULL because in the begining it doesn't point to any element so the obvious answer is:

```
last = list;
```

because list contains the address of the head which points to the next element